# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179

Tags: laravel, routes

I got this error to load my assets:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179
```

http://tahrircenter.com/assets/frontend/_img/_svg/chart.svg

[image]

Comment: you have no route for it

Comment: or if you want to open/download .. it must be located in `public/` folder

Comment: it is in public folder !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its due to case Sensitivity issue replace your url with

http://tahrircenter.com/assets/frontend/_img/_SVG/Chart.svg

Try above url hope it will work for you.